# How to sort each row of a 3D numpy array by another 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array of 2D points:

```
np.random.seed(0)   
a = np.random.rand(3, 4, 2) # each value is a 2D point
```

I would like to sort each row by the norm of every point

```
norms = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=2) # shape(3, 4)

indices = np.argsort(norms, axis=0) # indices of each sorted row
```

Now I would like to create an array with the same shape and values as `a`. that will have each row of 2D points sorted by their norm.

How can I achieve that?

I tried variations of np.take & np.take_along_axis but with no success.

for example:

```
np.take(a, indices, axis=1) # shape (3,3,4,2)
```

This samples `a` 3 times, once for each row in `indices`.
I would like to sample `a` just once. each row in `indices` has the columns that should be sampled from the corresponding row.

Comment: What variations did you try and how did they not succeed?

Comment: I'll be happy to nominate for reopening and post an answer when you fix the question

Comment: @MadPhysicist I edited the question with an example and a clarification. hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: @NinaKaprez Is the posted answer not what you are looking for? if not, could you please post a sample input and desired output?

Comment: What about take along axis? Also, shouldn't your argsort have axis=1? Or do you intend to sort columns rather than rows?

Comment: @MadPhysicist What about it? I did not manage to use it. I don't think it suits the purpose. I don't understand what is wrong with the question.

Comment: Nothing is really wrong. take_along_axis is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
norms = np.linalg.norm(a,axis=2) # shape(3,4)
indices = np.argsort(norms , axis=1)
np.take_along_axis(a, indices[:,:,None], axis=1)
```

output for your example:

```
[[[0.4236548  0.64589411]
  [0.60276338 0.54488318]
  [0.5488135  0.71518937]
  [0.43758721 0.891773  ]]

 [[0.07103606 0.0871293 ]
  [0.79172504 0.52889492]
  [0.96366276 0.38344152]
  [0.56804456 0.92559664]]

 [[0.0202184  0.83261985]
  [0.46147936 0.78052918]
  [0.77815675 0.87001215]
  [0.97861834 0.79915856]]]
```

Comment: no, the output should have the same shape as the variable 'a'.

Comment: @NinaKaprez It is the same shape. Is `a` not of shape `(3,4,2)`? If not, you would need to clarify better.

Comment: @Eshan, my bad. I think this is what I need. thanks! can you elaborate what indices[::None] does?

Comment: @NinaKaprez. It adds a new dimension at the `None` index.  `None is np.newaxis`.

Comment: @NinaKaprez You are welcome. Could not have said better than Mad Physicist's comment.