# What is the best way of rearranging subarrays in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of shape `(3,4,2)`, in which each subarray of shape `(4,2)` represents the 2d coordinates of 4 points. What I want is to sort each subarray based on the distances of the points from the origin.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3,4,2)
norms = np.linalg.norm(a,axis=2)
indices = np.argsort(norms,axis=1)
```

I know a simple for loop like

```
for ind,item in enumerate(indices): a[ind] = a[ind][item]
```

will solve the problem.

Is there a way to achieve this using `numpy` without a for loop? I have tried `np.take`, but with no success

```
a = np.random.rand(3,4,2)
norms = np.linalg.norm(a,axis=2)
indices = np.argsort(norms,axis=1)[...,None]

mask = np.tile(np.linspace(0,2,3)[:,None,None],(1,4,1))
indices = np.dstack((mask,indices)).astype(np.int)

sorted_array = np.take(a,indices)
```

Comment: Use `np.take_along_axis(a, indices[...,None], axis=1)`.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/a/64236058/4975981 answer your question?

Comment: @Ehsan yes, I saw this post hours earlier, unfortunately it was closed, but I’m interested, so I asked it here. I will delete this post if this violates the community’s rule.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky Does the answer to that post resolve your issue? if not, please elaborate on your question. Maybe with an example input output.

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, the answer resolve my issue. I had this issue because I misunderstood `np.take`, thanks!

Comment: @meTchaikovsky Glad it is resolved. I would suggest removing the post unless you are looking for different solutions. Thank you.